# How to pass the table variable to a stored procedure in SQL-Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL-Server. I have multiple procedures. Procedure1 filters the data on the basis of int value as below.

```
Procedure1 '70'
```

Another1 Procedure2, analyse the procedure1 output and filters it again on the basis of two values

```
Procedure2 '10', '20'
```

Now I want to write a Main procedure which receives 3 arguments and first pass the first argument to Procedure1 and then procedure2 receives the output of Procedure1 and second and third argument to perform analysis.

The code for Main procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spA_Main
(
@Argument1 int,
@Argument2 int,
@Argument3 int
)
AS
Begin

DECLARE @Task1Table TABLE
(
Userid      varchar(20),
Dtime       float,
Utime       float,
Days        int

)

--Task1
INSERT @Task1Table Execute Procedure1 @Argument1


--Task2

--SELECT * FROM @Task1Table
END
```

Comment: Read about table valued parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Create a function instead of a procedure, syntax will look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name ( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ = default ] [READONLY] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS @return_variable TABLE <table_type_definition>
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    BEGIN 
        function_body 
        RETURN
    END
[ ; ]
```

Have it return the data that first procedure would return, and store it in a temporary table. Than pass it as the argument to the second procedure.

Also I think it would make more sense to merge all these procedures into 1, since SQL is not so much a programing language as it is query language.

Comment: I liked your comment to keep it a single procedure because I can easily declare multiple table variables to store intermediary results though it will make the procedure very long.

Answer (score 1):

Passing Table in Procedure, you need prior to create Table Type.
e.g.

```
CREATE TYPE TaskTable AS TABLE
(
    Userid      varchar(20),
    Dtime       float,
    Utime       float,
    Days        int
)
```

You can use this table type variable in the procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourProcName
(
    @pTaskTable AS TaskTable READONLY
)
BEGIN
--your code
END
```

I thinks using above way, you can achieve your goal